# MVVM SimpleIOC Expression Blend can't create instance of ViewModelLocator

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light, expression-blend, blend

I've a trouble with setting up a design data with SimpleIOC.

I'm using a `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` class.

By registering it: `SimpleIoc.Default.Register<HttpClient>();` I'm receiving a error message form MVVMlight about multiple constructors. So I've searched for a workaround:

`SimpleIoc.Default.Register<HttpClient>(()=>new HttpClient());`

It's working in runtime but not in design mode. I'm receiving a error about already registered factory methods. And finally a message:

```
A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.Expression.Platform.InstanceBuilders.InstanceBuilderException' occurred in Microsoft.Expression.Platform.DLL

Additional information: Cannot create an instance of "ViewModelLocator".
```

Is there any workaround?

**UPDATE**

Made things working by making the **ViewModelLocator** constructor `static`. I don't know if it is a right thing to do.

Thank you for your time.

ViewModelLocator class:

```
    public class ViewModelLocator
{
    public HttpClient _httpClient;
    public const string TwitchHeader = "application/vnd.twitchtv.v3+json";
    public const string TwitchURL = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/";

    public static ViewModelLocator Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return Application.Current.Resources["Locator"] as ViewModelLocator;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the ViewModelLocator class.
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    public ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
        if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
        {
            // Create design time view services and models
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<HttpClient>(() => new HttpClient()); //Throws exception
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DesignDataService>();
        }
        else
        {
            // Create run time view services and models
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<HttpClient>(() => new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip })); //Throws exception
            _httpClient = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<HttpClient>();
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(TwitchHeader));
            _httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(TwitchURL);
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, TwitchDataService>();
        }

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ITwitchChannelModel,TwitchChannelModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ITwitchStreamModel, TwitchStreamModel>();

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ITwitchStreamsModel, TwitchStreamsModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ITwitchChannelsModel, TwitchChannelsModel>();



        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<TwitchChannelsViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<TwitchStreamsViewModel>();


        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<TwitchChannelViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<TwitchStreamViewModel>();

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();            
    }

    public MainViewModel Main
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
        }
    }

    public TwitchChannelsViewModel ChannelsViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<TwitchChannelsViewModel>();
        }
    }

    public static void Cleanup()
    {
        // TODO Clear the ViewModels
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no way for us to help you at all - we know nothing of `ViewModelLocator`, it's dependencies and it's constructor(s)

Comment: ViewModelLocator is part of a mvvmlight toolkit.

Comment: Carsten I've added the class code above.